# empty(), isset(), not_null() isn't returning the correct boolean

Tags: php, post, isset, isnull, is-empty

My code isn't working. I am submitting a form with everything empty, and the page isn't redirecting me back to the home page. Here is my code:

```
    var_dump($_POST['comment']);
    var_dump($_POST['rating']);

    if (!is_null($_POST['comment']) || !empty($_POST['rating'])) {
        $comment = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'comment', FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);

        $movie_name = $_GET['m'];
        $userid = $_POST['userid'];
        $movieid = $_POST['movieid'];
        $rating = $_POST['rating'];
        echo 'not empty';
     } else {
        echo 'empty';
     }
```

var_dump is returning: string(0) "" string(0) "" , it is echoing 'not empty'; I tried everything, isset, empty, is_null, it wont work. What is wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Before 'else' should be a '}' sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing a "}", and then write the condition as :

```
if ( (!empty($_POST['comment'])) AND (!empty($_POST['rating']))) {
```

Comment: It works, but now, if a field is open and another is filled, it echoes not empty

Comment: because I used an "AND",  now you need to change the condition to achieve what you want, it's a trivial task.